# Spring Boot java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, illegalargumentexception

When trying to launch my project I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'

I configure my database connection in an application.properties file that looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

And have an maven/spring-boot start script that gets the VM options:

```
-DJDBC_DATABASE_URL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project"
-DJDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME="postgres"
-DJDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD="postgres"
```

A few tests showed me, that the VM options are completely not resolved but I have no idea on how to fix this.

My IDE is IntelliJ Community Edition.

It worked fine. Today I upgraded the project to Java 15 but in my opinion this should not result in such a problem.

Do you have any idea where the config gets overwritten or something?

Answer (score 0):

When you quote just the value, the quote characters become part of the value, which means that the URL now starts with a `"jdbc`, so you get error saying "must start with `jdbc`".

You have two options:

1. Don't quote:

   ```
   -DJDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project
   -DJDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
   -DJDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
   ```
2. Quote the whole argument:

   ```
   "-DJDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project"
   "-DJDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres"
   "-DJDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres"
   ```

Comment: I tried this, but this sadly does not solve my problem.